# Truffle Test: How to send ether to a contract from a contract?

Tags: truffle, javascript, truffle-test, modifiers

Would like to test the modifier below

```
modifier isNotAContract(){
    require (msg.sender == tx.origin, 'Contracts are not allowed to interact.');
    _;
}
```

How can I invoke a function using this modifier by a contract?

Javascript syntax prefered!

Comment: Modifiers can only be used in solidity functions, not from an external call directly.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I have a function using the modifier. How can I simulate a call from a contract? Like `await a.buy( {value: 5000000, from: contract_two});` without actually writing and deploying a contract?

Comment: You can't, you'll need to create a testing or mock contract for that purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contracts:

```
contract A {
    modifier isNotAContract(){
        require (msg.sender == tx.origin, 'Contracts are not allowed to interact.');
        _;
    } 

    function f() public isNotAContract {
        // ...
    }
}

contract B {
    A a = new A();
    function f() public {
        a.f();
    }
}
```

In Truffle:

```
var b = await B.new()
await b.f();    // should fail
```